# First time using jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Working with Jquery UI tabs and the set up quite easy, but now as for trouble shooting I am having a couple issues.

To begin with this is a picture of my screen : [image]

off the "get - go" it is appearnt that the tabs should not be looking like this. Further more if you notice right after the tabs portion (Recommendation Two, Recommentation One, No Recommondations) you notice a banner, and footer. Well those should not be there, as those are my global "views" if you will so every page gets gets the banner and that footer.

This is how I set up my tabs in my view :

```
echo '<div id="recommendations">';
        echo form_open('/admin/c_applicationmaintance/addNewApplication/' . urlencode('4'));


        echo '<div id="tabs">';

            echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li><a href="recommendation1">Recommendation One</a></li>';
                echo '<li><a href="recommendation2">Recommendation Two</a></li>';   
                echo '<li><a href="norecommendations">No Recommendations</a></li>';
            echo '</ul>';

            echo '<div id="recommendation1">';
                echo '<textarea name="txtEssay" rows="10", cols="50" placeholder="Scholarship Essay">'. set_value("txtEssay") . '</textarea>';
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div id="recommendation1">';
                echo '<textarea name="txtEssay" rows="10", cols="50" placeholder="Scholarship Essay">'. set_value("txtEssay") . '</textarea>';
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div id="norecommendations">';
                echo '<textarea name="txtEssay" rows="10", cols="50" placeholder="Scholarship Essay">'. set_value("txtEssay") . '</textarea>';
            echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';

        echo form_submit('', 'Next >>');
        echo form_close();      
        echo form_open('/admin/c_applicationmaintance/addNewApplication/' . urlencode('3'));
        echo form_submit('', '<< Back');
        echo form_close();
        echo '</div>';
```

As for debugging, taking a look at the chrome dev tools I notice every time I keep switching in between tabs I get the following errors:

[image]

any guidance in the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add # in href of a list item so instead of

```
<li><a href="recommendation1">Recommendation One</a></li>
```

enter

```
<li><a href="#recommendation1">Recommendation One</a></li>
```

because jQuery is trying to target div with id recommendation1